# Why I am getting this "The issuer '(null)' is invalid" error

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created an web api via CORE6, and I have followed the tutorials.  Everything seems to be working not until I have put authorization to the endpoint.  When accessing to an authorized endpoint, I am getting a 401 Unauthorized response.  Upon further investigation, I think the error is because of this one: WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer '(null)' is invalid"

---

In my appsettings.json here is the value for the Issuer:

```
    "Jwt": {
        "Key": "lectureTest123456",
        "Issuer": "https://localhost:44387",
        "Audience": "https://localhost:44387",
        "Subject": "JWTServiceAccessToken"
    },
```

And in my Program.cs here is how it is declared

---

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;    
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
```

---

and in the generation of the token, this is the code.

```
    private string GetToken()
    {
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),                
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, "1516239022"),
            new Claim("userId" , "1"),
            new Claim("name", "Jason"),
            new Claim("userName", "Jason"),
            new Claim("email", "jason@gmail.com")
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("lectureTest123456"));
        var singIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _configuration["Jwt: Issuer"],
                _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                signingCredentials: singIn
                );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    }
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I use your code to test, but your problem does not occur, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?